# How to authorize on site without login-form page?

Tags: python, python-requests

How to authorize on site without login-form page. This site uses modal form with url like this http://example-site.com/#myModal.

I tried:

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {"login_name":"admin", "login_password":"password"}
url = "http://example-site.com/#myModal"
r = s.post(url, data=data, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = s.get('http://example-site/forauthorizedusers.html',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )
print(html.text)
```

In result of this code I got html page for non-authorized users.

HTML code of site is:

```
form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name" class="input-small" style="margin-top: -2px;" placeholder="Login">
<input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" style="margin-top: -2px;"  class="input-small" placeholder="Password">                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<button style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: -2px;margin-left: 0px;" type="submit" nclick="submit();" class="btn btn-info " >Log in</button>
<input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html = s.get('http://example-site/forauthorizedusers.html', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'password'), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/